# How to check if a page/component is unpublished from a particular target in coreservice?

Tags: core-service

I am trying to get the publish state of a page/component. But not able to find a method which will tell me if an item is UNPUBLISHED from a particular target. I am using CoreService.

client.GetListPublishInfo(pageUri) does not give me the information if the page/component is unpublished. Or I am looking at a wrong method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use following if your requirement is just to check the status

```
public bool IsPublished(string itemId, string publicationTargetId, 
bool isPublishedInContext)
```

Answer (score 6):

To check if an item is published to a known PublicationTarget use the method as described by @Raj

```
public bool IsPublished(string itemId, string publicationTargetId, bool isPublishedInContext)
```

To see which PublicationTargets a known item is published to use

```
public PublishInfoData[] GetListPublishInfo(string itemId);
```

You can then see information about the items publish status like

```
foreach(PublishInfoData info in PublishInfoDataArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Target: {0} Time: {1}", info.PublicationTarget.Title, info.PublishedAt.ToString()));
}
```