# How to get publishing status of a Component using Core Service?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service, publishing

How to get publishing status of any Component using Core Service? I want to fetch those TCM Ids which have been published successfully, un-published successfully and failed for a specific Publication Target.

Comment: There is an already question and answer for this, https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/how-to-check-if-a-page-component-is-unpublished-from-a-particular-target-in-core/7474

Comment: Hi Velmurugan , the code provided on the above link does not work for me.

Comment: what you have tried so far and any errors please edit your question and share the error/logs details?

Comment: The requirement is like - 10 components sent to publishing queue and 5 components successfully published, 3 components successfully unpublished and 2 components failed. I want those component TCM Ids through core service code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use To filter capabilities of the Publishing queue, take a look at the **PublishTransactionsFilterData** and its properties. Use the filter paired with **GetSystemWideList** or **GetSystemWideListXml** and you can obtain an array of 
PublishTransactionData or their Ids.

Example coreservice code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;

namespace PublishingQueue
{
    static class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            var client = GetClient("localhost:7086", @"username", "password");

            var filter = new PublishTransactionsFilterData()
            {
                StartDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2),
                EndDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.Success
            };

            XElement publishTransactions = client.GetSystemWideListXml(filter);

            foreach (XElement queueItem in publishTransactions.Descendants())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID  = " + queueItem.Attribute("ID").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Title = " + queueItem.Attribute("Title").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("ItemUri = " + queueItem.Attribute("ItemID").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("User = " + queueItem.Attribute("User").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Publication = " + queueItem.Attribute("Publication").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("PublicationTarget = "+ queueItem.Attribute("PublicationTarget").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("ItemPath = " + queueItem.Attribute("ItemPath").Value);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        static ICoreService GetClient(string hostname, string username, string password)
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding()
            {
                MaxBufferSize = 4194304, // 4MB
                MaxBufferPoolSize = 4194304,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4194304,
                ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = 4194304, // 4MB
                    MaxArrayLength = 4194304,
                },
                Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity()
                {
                    Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport,
                    Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
                    {
                        ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
                    }
                }
            };

            hostname = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", hostname.StartsWith("https") ? "" : "https://", hostname, hostname.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/");
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(hostname + "/webservices/CoreService201603.svc/basicHttp");
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICoreService>(binding, endpoint);

            var credentialBehaviour = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials>();
            credentialBehaviour.UserName.UserName = username;
            credentialBehaviour.UserName.Password = password;
            return factory.CreateChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, Thanks for your help. With the reference above code the my implementation works. Thanks for your assistance. I have added just extra two filter to get the results for specific publication and publication targets -``ForRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData { IdRef = "tcm:0-32-1" },
                PublicationTarget = new LinkToPublicationTargetData { IdRef = "tcm:0-12-65537" }``

Comment: Good to now it helps to resolved your issue, please upvote

Comment: Hi Velmurugan, one more input is required. How to get those components from publishing queue which has been unpublished successfully?

Comment: Please create a new question for that

Comment: I have raised a new question for the query. Thanks @AtilaSos. Here is the question reference - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/how-to-get-those-tcm-ids-which-has-been-unpublished-successfully-from-publishing