# How to get those TCM IDs which has been unpublished successfully from publishing queue using Tridion Core Service?

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

I need to fetch those TCM IDs from publishing queue which has been unpublished successfully using Tridion Core Service.

Comment: Hi Sudip. It would be useful if you could tell us what investigation you've done so far and what problems you've encountered please. A simple Google search should give some ideas of where to start (using both C# and PowerShell): https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tridion+core+service+publish+transactions&oq=tridion+core+service+publish+transactions

Comment: Hi @JonathanWilliams, I have used PublishTransactionState but that will give me only publishing success and failed result. I want those item which has been unpublished successfully

Comment: Off the top of my head, the `PublishTransactionData` object should contain details about the Publish Instruction.

Comment: I am getting published success and failed data through PublishTransactionData. I want to fetch the unpublished success and failed data.

Comment: @SudipGhorai, please add the comment and any examples to your original question to help others find this question and all of its context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use `PublishTransactionsFilterData` filter to retrieve all publish transactions based on your criteria.

```
                PublishTransactionsFilterData ptfd = new PublishTransactionsFilterData()
            {
                PublicationTarget = new LinkToPublicationTargetData() { IdRef = "tcm:0-19-65537" },
                ForRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData() { IdRef = "tcm:0-127-1" },
                PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.Success
            };
 IdentifiableObjectData[] transactions = CoreServiceConnector.Client.GetSystemWideList(ptfd);
```

However, this filter has no info on resolve purpose, so you will have to read each transaction, get its `ResolveInstruction.Purpose` and check if its `ResolvePurpose.UnPublish`:

```
 foreach (PublishTransactionData transaction in transactions)
            {
                PublishTransactionData transactionData = (PublishTransactionData)CoreServiceConnector.Client.Read(transaction.Id, new ReadOptions());

                if (transactionData.Instruction.ResolveInstruction.Purpose == ResolvePurpose.UnPublish)
                {
                   // do something
                }

            }
```

Just an update, you have to read every transaction again with client.read because `ResolveInstruction` is not available on `GetSystemWideList()` because of lazy load.

Comment: Note that the Publish Queue in CME also shows Publish or Unpublish, so that info is available in the list data. I don’t have a system at hand to check which property it is, but I expect a `PublishTransactionData` property to reflect Publish/Unpublish in the list data (no need for full loads).

Comment: its shown as Action="1" for Unpublish, Action="0" for publish, or Action="2" for republish, and min value of integer for uknown by client if XML is retrieved instead of objects.

Comment: So yeah, LINQ can be used to filter based on XML property if GetSystemWideListXml() is used.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoMilic, the reference code and instruction is really very helpful. my issue has been resolved by following your resolution steps.