# How to Filter Out all the Published Components from the list of all the components for a particular publication

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

I want to filter out all the published components from the list of all the components for a particular publication. Currently I am getting a list of all the components and in that I want to put a filter so that

I can get a list of only those components that are published, as it will improve efficiency.
Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to  tridion stack exchange please refer to following link for more details—> https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19521/how-to-get-publishing-status-of-a-component-using-core-service

Comment: Hi Archintya, Welcome to Tridion Stack exchange.  It would be useful if you could tell us what investigation you've done so far and what problems you've encountered, please. A simple Google search should give some ideas of where to start (using both C# and PowerShell)